# limit sshd to use only ssh-ed25519 keys to authenticate

Tags: sshd

I am trying to configure my sshd on ubuntu 18.04 to accept only ed25519 keys to authenticate, at the moment the server accepts ssh-rsa and ssh-ed25519. Any idea to achieve that? thanks!

Comment: I referenced your question here: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/222006/37051

Answer (score 4, accepted):

man `sshd_config` and man `ssh_config` , is mandatory to read .

`PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes` is what you want to use .

Comment: PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519 worked for me, thanks!